# Laravel 5.2 - Auth::attempt() method does not persistently logs in users

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

I'm trying to manually login and register users in my website, following the instructions I found in [Laravel's Documentantion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users), when I try to log in a registered user, with the correct credentials, `Auth::attempt()` logs in the user and returns true, however the user is lost in subsequent requests.

Here's the controller used to login users:

```
public function login() {
    $username = Request::input('username');
    $password = Request::input('password');

    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
      return redirect()->route('accounts', [$username]);
    } else {
      return redirect('/');
    }
  }
```

After redirecting to the user page, there is no user session.

After checking if Sessions are working properly (I'm using the database driver), I have noticed that Laravel creates session data into the database right after the execution of `Auth::attempt()`, however the `user_id` field is `NULL`, which is why users does not remain logged in. My users table contains all the necessary fields, with only 3 additional fields (`first_name`, `last_name` and `username`). I cannot figure out why the `attempt()` method is not correctly creating the user session after successfully authenticating the user credentials, even though Sessions are working fine.

EDIT: Even using the AuthController methods for creating and logging in users it does not work, I get the same results, a Session with no `user_id` information. What could possibly cause Sessions/Authentication to behave like this?